# Database mirroring on Rackspace or Xeround

Tags: database, load-balancing, mirroring, rackspace, xeround

I´m running 2 servers on Rackspace. I have set up a load balancer that balances the traffic between these two servers.

Each of these servers runs a Glassfish v3 server with a Java EE application on it, that offers a web interface to write some data into server database. The problem is that I need to have the same data on each database (server 1 database and server 2 database).

A resolution to this problem is mirroring of databases.

I would like to ask if there is some automated system to mirror these databases inside the rackspace?
Furthermore I ve found Xendros database cloud that is able to work with Rackspace Cloud. Is it possible to mirror these databases inside the Xeround? 
Or are there any better solutions ?

Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xeround you do not need to mirror your database, you create a single database instance and direct your application servers to work with this instance.
For more information you are welcomed to visit our web site http://www.xeround.com

Comment: okay :) but if we have big traffic on each application server -> wont this traffic affect also concrete database server? I mean if we will have 2 application servers and only one database server

Comment: What if the database server goes down?